# Runtimewarning This Channel is already in use

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm configuring some leds and buttons on my raspberry pi, and when running the script the system warns me a channel is already in use. I tried looking for a solution, and a tip was to do a `GPIO.Cleanup()` in a finally clause. I tried, but it keeps failing. Any idea why? The error points to `GPIO.setup(button_pin, GPIO.IN)` but not sure to add these lines of code in my try clause?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os 
import time

# Hide Warnings
# GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Assign GPIO pin numbers

button_pin = 3 # Input Pin
button_led = 14 # Output Pin
green_led = 22 # Output Pin
red_led = 27 # Output Pin
# ir_receiver_pin = 17

# Use BCM pin numbering
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# 1. GPIO Setup

GPIO.setup(button_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(button_led, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(green_led, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(red_led, GPIO.OUT)

# 2. Button Led Behaviour on Startup

def button_led_on():
    GPIO.output(button_led, GPIO.HIGH)

def button_led_off():
    GPIO.output(button_led, GPIO.LOW)

def button_flicker_startup():
    a = 1
    while a < 4:
        button_led_on()
        time.sleep(0.3)
        button_led_off()
        time.sleep(0.3)
        a = a + 1
    button_led_on() # LED is high when Pi is on

# 3. Define front led behaviour on startup

def green_led_on():
    GPIO.output(green_led, GPIO.HIGH)

def green_led_off():
    GPIO.output(green_led, GPIO.LOW)

def red_led_on():
    GPIO.output(red_led, GPIO.HIGH)

def red_led_off():
    GPIO.output(red_led, GPIO.LOW)

def boot_flicker():
    time.sleep(1.0)
    green_led_on()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    green_led_off()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    green_led_on()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    green_led_off()
    red_led_on()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    red_led_off()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    green_led_on() # LED is high when Pi is on

# 4. Main program

try:
    button_flicker_startup()
    boot_flicker()
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(button_pin, GPIO.FALLING)
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

except:
    pass

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I could use `GPIO.setwarnings(False)` but this is just hiding the error and would like to avoid that.

EDIT: My Raspberry Pi is using a Hifiberry dac who is using GPIO 2 and 3 for configuration. Could it be related to that?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the main bit to this:

```
x = True
try:
    while x:
        button_flicker_startup()
        boot_flicker()
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(button_pin, GPIO.FALLING)
        os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

except:
    pass

finally:
    x = False
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

because the functions are running, now we force them to stop running and then we cleanup.
I've used this video to help me, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEi_dT9KDJI&t=257s : 
I would watch it if I was you, I goes in depth about what you need/want.

Comment: That doesn't change a thing. Do we need to stop the code before the cleanup ?

Comment: I think you need to.